# Modelica : Simulation of temperature rise in a cable - How to do?

Tags: simulation, physics, modelica, openmodelica

I am a beginner on modelica. I wanted to transpose a model found on a paper (on internet) to a modelica model.
Here is the paper :
[Insulated Cable Temperature Calculation and Numerical Simulation](https://www.matec-conferences.org/articles/matecconf/pdf/2018/34/matecconf_ifcae-iot2018_03014.pdf)
I am stuck in rewritting the fomulas. Second derivative on a variable different of time --> i don't know how to do.

Another way I was thinking is to use the Thermal/HeatTransfer library. But here too, I don't know how to put the blocks togethers... I think this is due to a big lack in thermodynamic knowledge from my side.
--> I don't know what block to use to simulate the conductor and the insulation layer.

Maybe this is something too difficult ?

If someone has an idea on how to start, it will be a pleasure to read you :)

I tried to use the Thermal library :
[Using heat transfert lib.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxRCv.png)

I have a current source and a resistance.
The resistance will change depending on the temperature involved by the current in the resistance.
I use 0.004 as alpha for the relationship R=R20*(1+alpha(T-Tamb)).

Let's say I have a 1 meter copper conductor with a crossSection of S=16mm² = 15.10^-6m²
then the initial resistance is R = rho.L/S ≃ 1.07mΩ at 20°C
Following this example of cable : [Bayka 16mm²](https://www.bayka.de/en/service/technical-information/current-rating-pvc-insulated-low-voltage-cables/)
To get 70°C at the surface of the conductor, then the max current for a single 16mm² wire cable is 107A in air, and 160A in earth.

I took, in my example, random value of thermal conductance and capacity to get an approximative temperature near the one given in the table (~70°C).

Is this model is the good one for an insulated cable ? (no considering values)
Or I forgot something? Maybe I am wrong in the position of the blocks ?

What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks reasonable to me, might be easier to use the same component for heat conduction (heat resistor or heat conductance, not both) in order to be able to compare the two values. The mathematical formulas for radial heat conduction can be found here e.g. https://web2.clarkson.edu/projects/subramanian/ch330/notes/Conduction%20in%20the%20Cylindrical%20Geometry.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to change the way to simulate heat dissipation. I made a 3D cube, with a capacitance and 6 conductances (for each surfaces).
Connecting several cubes in serie/parallel will permits me to generate an equivalent model of a 3D conductor. I am still writing it as i am doing that on my free time..
My goal is to use these elements assembly to simulate not only a wire but also different design...
I think this looks like a "finite element" method (maybe?) so calculation time will be pretty long, but surely more accurate than the previous model i use (i hope)

Comment: it is finite volume and should work fine but due to the very small lengths I suggest to use the 1D approach you started with for cables, otherwise your simulation might become very slow without improving the quality of your results.

Comment: Yep, I just tried with 400 elements, contening 6 heatport + 2 electrical port.... that take several minutes. So you are right, i will try to design with a 1D approach... I don't know if i will be able to do it as i'm not familiar enough with modelica :) But thanks for the help !